# What is the correct way to serialize objects on orientation change using onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-orientation

I am serializing `logCalculation` method object on orientation change.

On orientation change, the value returned by `logCalculation` is preserved in `Bundle outState`. So it should show the data.

However, on orientation change, the list is empty. It is not taking the value from `savedInstanceState.getSerializable("calcLogs")`

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my code -

ArrayList logss = new ArrayList();

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("calcLogs", calcLogs);
    }


if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    try
    {
        calcLogs = (ArrayList<LogChartData>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("calcLogs");
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


if(calcLogs == null)
{
    calcLogs = logCalculation(Curcal.getTime());
}

public ArrayList<LogChartData> logCalculation(final Date dt) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {


        logss.clear();
        alert.clear();
        logss = fillChartData(dt);

        // Some more data here..

        }
    }

        return logss;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `super.onSaveInstanceState()` so the bundle gets processed as needed

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("calcLogs", calcLogs);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: Ah good catch. Necessary to call it only after putSerializable ? Does it make the difference to call after serializing ?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary to call after because you want your data to have been added before processing.

Comment: well it is still null data. Is it something to do with the method `logCalculation`. It was a void method previously returning nothing. I returned only logss. However I can see more variables it sets. Can't the void method be serialized or do I have to serialize the variables that it sets ?

Comment: In which method do you do savedState.getSerialable ?

Comment: I does it onCreateView(). However here also I haven't defined super.onCreateView(). Can it be a problem ?

Comment: Further testing showed that savedInstanceState is null always so this condition never gets true - `if (savedInstanceState != null) { get serializable object}`.